# Intent cannot be resolved

Tags: android

I cant find any problem. I'm new to android. Can someone help me to solve it?

```
 public void onClick(View v)
{
    if(v.getId()==R.id.btnSave)
    {
        database=db.getWritableDatabase();
        database.execSQL("INSERT INTO UserDetails(Username,Email,Hp,Company,Position,Address)VALUES('"+Name.getText()+"','"+Email.getText()+"','"+Hp.getText()+"','"+Company.getText()+"','"+Position.getText()+"','"+Address.getText()+"')" );
        Toast.makeText(this,"Data Inserted To Sqlite Database",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else  if(v.getId()==R.id.btnShow)
    {
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,ShowdataListview.class);
        startActivity(intent);
     }
```

i cant run it. It say can't resolve the symbol of intent and startActivity
(android.content.Intent)
in Activity cannot be applied
to .

Comment: You need to add a **lot more detail**. Have you included the `ShowdataListview` class (and `Intent` class, and `Activity` ...)?

Comment: done added thanks for the reply sir

Comment: Your class is extending to Fragment or AppCompatActivity or Activity?

Comment: AppCompatActivity . Sir

Comment: Have you declared `import android.content.Intent` on top?

Comment: Forgot about it Sir, thanks for solving my problem and sorry for my careless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i cant run it. It say can't resolve the symbol of intent and
>   startActivity

Make sure you have declared this on top

```
import android.content.Intent
```